# passing JSON data from one controller to another controller angularJS

Tags: angularjs

i want to pass the data from one controller to another controller, i am 
Getting Data in `$scope.imagegallerys` variable and i am able to set the data into `SetJson();`

**controller 1**

```
function imageGalleryController($scope,$http,myService){
    var urlBase = "http://localhost:8084/Apc/api/";
    $http.get(urlBase + '/gallerylist').
    success(function(Data) {
    $scope.imagegallerys = Data;
    myService.setJson($scope.imagegallerys);
 });    
}
```

I want get data to anther controller however getJson() is not returning any value or object.

**controller 2**

```
    function categoryController($scope,myService){
    $scope.myreturn = myService.getJson();
    }
```

**Factory**

```
    function myService(){
      var imagegallerys = null;//the object to hold our data
      return{
      getJson:function(){
      return imagegallerys;
      },
      setJson:function(value){
      imagegallerys = value;
       }
   }

angular.module('Abc')
.controller('categoryController', categoryController)
.controller('imageGalleryController',imageGalleryController)
.factory('myService',myService);`
```

Comment: use `$rootScope.abc='your value'` , and you can that value in other controller.

Comment: I m new in angularjs.So pleses Explain it proper wey so i implement it.In my coad

Comment: do you tried this myService.setJson(Data)? maybe $scope problems?

Answer (score 1):

This is your first controller:

```
function imageGalleryController($scope,$http,myService,$rootScope){
    var urlBase = "http://localhost:8084/Apc/api/";
    $http.get(urlBase + '/gallerylist').
    success(function(Data) {
    $rootScope.imagegallerys = Data;
    myService.setJson($scope.imagegallerys);
 });    
}
```

And below is your second controller:

```
function categoryController($scope,myService,$rootScope){
    console.log($rootScope.imagegallerys);
    $scope.myreturn = myService.getJson();
    }
```

I hope this solution help you , If not please inform me

Comment: @ashwin Kumbhare , this answer is helpful to you?

Comment: Trying to implement

Comment: @ashwinKumbhare , if it helps to you then don't forgot to appreciate my work. And mark my answer as a accpt , so it can also helpful to other

Comment: i have tried with this one however still not able to get the data in second controller.

Comment: @ashwinKumbhare , are you sure? becuase this solution is working in my 3-4 project

Comment: yes @chirag, i believe we did the same, the thing we couldn't clarify was the use of "$scope.ImageData = $rootScope.imagegallerys;". is it used anywhere

Comment: @ashwinKumbhare , Check the answer , i update the answer

Comment: please find the reqired changes you have asked. my code still not working  (1)controller
function imageGalleryController($scope,$http,$rootScope,myService){
var urlBase = "http://localhost:8084/Solution/api/";
        $http.get(urlBase + '/gallerylist').
        success(function(Data) {
        $rootScope.imagegallerys = Data;        
        myService.setJson($scope.imagegallerys);
        });  
   
        }

(2)controller
function categoryController($scope,$rootScope,myService){
   console.log($rootScope.imagegallerys);
   $scope.myreturn = myService.getJson();


        }

Comment: (3)Factory
function myService(){
 
    var imagegallerys = null;//the object to hold our data
     return{
     getJson:function(){
       return imagegallerys;
     },
     setJson:function(value){
      imagegallerys = value;
     }
     }
}


 angular.module('image')
.controller('categoryController', categoryController)
 .controller('imageGalleryController',imageGalleryController)
 .factory('myService',myService);